# How do you issue a beep sound in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

We have an input field via a bar code scanner and we want to make a beep sound when the field is ready for a new input.  I cannot find an example with sample code how to do this.  Is there a way to generate a beep sound in visualforce?

Comment: Is this (http://kalyanlanka.blogspot.nl/2012/09/working-with-jplayer-and-visualforce.html) something ?

Comment: It seems fairly complicated.  Is there a simpler solution to generate a beep sound?